# QGIS - extract raster values greater than 0

Tags: qgis, raster

How can I extract values > 0 from an overall raster?

I have a water level grid and a DTM from which I've derived flood depths (using the raster calculator) but obviously the final result contains negative values where there is no flooding.

I want to remove these values (or set them to null) just leaving the positive flood depths.

Many thanks

Comment: How about creating an unsigned 8+ bit raster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Raster Calculator for this, see "Using a Mask" [here](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - thought it would be an easy one!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Based on the raster calculator you can use the following formula:

RASTER/(RASTER>0)

This way you will get all values less than 0 as No Data

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but the "Sieve" function in the QGIS raster menu (gdal tools) should output a raster containing only values up to a specific value.